# The plastic film is peeling off the corners and edges of some of my kitchen cabinets - how can I simply fix this?

Tags: kitchens, cabinets

The corners and edges of some of my kitchen cabinets are peeling (the clear film over the colour).
How can I easily fix this without redoing the whole door/surface (ie just fixing the small peeling section)?
I’d like a good finish!

[image: Cabinet with protective film peeling at corner]

Comment: Another angle of the peeling area, maybe with some hand-drawn red circles to highlight what, exactly, it is that you're concerned about. I see something at the very top of the corner piece, but I'm not sure if it's the protective film that jay613 is referring to or if it's actually a small chip in the laminate. The rest does look like the protective shipping film hasn't been removed.

Comment: Grab the peeling corner, pull, dispose of *temporary protective film for shipping and installation* - a phase of life which has passed for your cabinets and appliances.

Comment: Thank you both. Maybe it’s the protective plastic… Ecnerwal, your message made me laugh!! There is a tiny bit of evidence of another plastic layer that was removed originally (form over what you see) but perhaps this is supposed to be removed too. I’ll have a look…

Answer (score 5):

It's hard to tell from a photo but that looks like protective film that you are *supposed* to remove. It protects it during transport and installation. I think I see some on the dishwasher (or whatever it is) below too ... the frayed edges halfway down look typical of this stuff.

If you like the look of the plastic film you can buy similar stuff, like clear shelf liner, that will be a little thicker and won't peel as easily, though you'll have to replace it once in a while.

Comment: Thank you:) It’s very hard to see if it’s supposed to be removed. I think not as it looks perfect everywhere else and has a lovely finish, plus there is evidence in places of a film on top of this which was removed which I think was the protective one. I may have to take a leap of faith and try pulling it off - hope for the best. And if it’s a disaster I’ll devote some time to perfecting film application:)